# database query help wanted

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to limit the results a mysql select query returns with a condition?

For example I have a reviews table:

> review_id, member_id, text, date

And I'd like to get the latest 10 reviews but member_id = 123 should only be taken once

Can this be achieved with a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My interpretation of the problem:

- the 10 most recent reviews
- including *at most* 1 review with `member_id` = 123

I'm going to solve this by:

- starting with the full reviews result set
- removing all reviews that have `member_id` = 123 *except for the most recent one*
- from the modified result set, take the 10 most recent

Here's the query:

```
create view newest123 as ( -- this gets the newest review for member_id 123
  select * 
   from reviews 
   where member_id = 123 
   order by date desc limit 1
)

select * 
from (
  select * from newest123
  union
  select *                    -- all the reviews that aren't for member_id 123
    from reviews 
    where member_id != 123) filtered
order by date desc limit 10   -- sort 'em and take the top 10
```